# Best way to filter and extract from a list of custom type?

Tags: haskell

I have a data type that represents command-line options:

`data Flag = Verbose | Help | Buffer Int deriving (Show, Eq)`

When the program runs, I get a list of `Flag`, corresponding to the options the user specified. For example, `[Buffer 10, Verbose]`.

My question is, what's the best way to extract the `Int` value from a `Buffer` in `[Flag]`?
The list may not even have a `Buffer`.
All I'm coming up with is some sort of convoluted traversal/fold that uses a `case` statement to filter out `Buffer` from the other `Flag`s.

Comment: If the list may not have a buffer, you really want a function of type `[Flag] -> Maybe Int`, and let something else worry about how to handle a return value of `Nothing`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a starting point, consider this function:

```
buffers :: [Flag] -> [Int]
buffers xs = [b | Buffer b <- xs]
```

It returns a list of just the `Int`s from inside of the `Buffer`s. For `[Verbose, Help]`, it will return `[]`. For `[Buffer 10, Verbose]`, it will return `[10]`. For `[Buffer 123, Buffer 456]`, it will return `[123, 456]`.

Now you have a `[Flag] -> [Int]`. If you also come up with an `[Int] -> Int`, you can compose them to get the `[Flag] -> Int` that you originally asked for, so now it's up to you how you get a single integer out of that list.

`listToMaybe` is one approach. It will return `Nothing` if the list is empty, or `Just` the first element otherwise. Compose it with `fromMaybe` to set a default buffer size if none is provided.

Alternatively, you can combine multiple buffer arguments somehow. `maximum (0:buffers xs)` will return the largest buffer size that was specified, or 0 if none were. (Without the `0:`, your program would crash if no buffer sizes were specified.) `sum (buffers xs)` will return the sum of all of the buffer sizes that were specified (and automatically returns 0 if none were, since the empty sum is 0).

Comment: Thank you, I came up with this: `getBufferSize fs = if length sizes > 0 then sizes!!0 else 0   where sizes = [size | Buffer size <- fs]`

Comment: @paperduck `case sizes of x:_ -> x; [] -> 0` would be more idiomatic, because the `(!!)` function is not total, so it's best to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Generally, prefer pattern matching to `length`, `(!!)`, `head`, or `tail`. All of those are implemented with pattern matching,and are generally less efficient or safe than pattern matching.

Comment: It's important to note that this relies on the `fail` function of `[]` and is therefore potentially error-prone in the future. (See the MonadFail proposal)

Comment: @schuelermine no, `[]` has a MonadFail instance, so this will continue to work.

Comment: Oh, OK, thanks. I wasn't aware the transition plan was that solid.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple solution to this.

First, implement a type to represent a *complete* description of your program's behavior:

```
data Mode = NormalMode { verbose :: Bool, buffer :: Int } | HelpMode
```

Then, implement an update function to update the arguments based on *one* flag and a default argument array:

```
defaults :: Mode
defaults = NormalMode { verbose = False, buffer = defaultBuffer }
 -- assuming defaultBuffer is defined somewhere

update :: Flag -> Mode -> Mode
update Help _ = HelpMode
update _ HelpMode = HelpMode
update Verbose NormalMode { buffer = b } = NormalMode { verbose = True, buffer = b }
update (Buffer n) NormalMode { verbose = v } = NormalMode { verbose = v, buffer = n }
```

Then, to parse a list of `Flag`s, just use `foldr` or `foldl`:

```
parseFlagsR :: [Flag] -> Mode
parseFlagsR = foldr update defaults
 -- This prioritizes the leftmost Buffer flag

parseFlagsL :: [Flag] -> Mode
parseFlagsL = foldl (flip update) defaults
 -- This prioritizes the rightmost Buffer flag
```

You could then get the buffer in any of the following ways, though I recommend the last one:

```
safeGetBuffer :: Mode -> Maybe Int
safeGetBuffer NormalMode { buffer = b } = Just b
safeGetBuffer _ = Nothing

getBufferWith :: Int -> Mode -> Int
getBufferWith _ NormalMode { buffer = b } = b
getBufferWith n _ = n

getBuffer :: Mode -> Int
getBuffer = getBufferWith defaultBuffer
 -- defaultBuffer from earlier, again, assuming it's defined.
```

This solution is more general than Joseph Sible's answer, and might be useful when it comes to extracting the verbosity value. This also explicitly formulates the precedence of flags and conveniently bundles all updating operations into one.

Additionally, if you want to know more about general implementations of this, I suggest you familiarize yourself with Lenses and other Optics.